# build x264 failed on apple M1, No working C compiler found

Tags: apple-m1, x264, libx264

1. Apple M1, clang

```
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

2. x264 [version x264-snapshot-20191217-2245](http://ftp.videolan.org/pub/x264/snapshots/x264-snapshot-20191217-2245-stable.tar.bz2)
3. configure

```
 ./configure --prefix=/tmp/  --enable-static
```

4. config.log

```
checking for -Werror=unknown-warning-option... yes
checking for -mdynamic-no-pic... yes
x264 configure script
Command line options: "--prefix=/tmp/" "--enable-static"

checking whether gcc works... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) -mdynamic-no-pic -arch armv7  -Werror=unknown-warning-option    -lm -arch armv7 -o conftest
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a (5 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd (3 slices)
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
int main (void) {  return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
DIED: No working C compiler found.
```

Comment: How about using something newer for x264 source? https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264/

Comment: @nobody555 thanks, the newer source works. Can you post the comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x264 source snapshot tarballs have not been updated for a long time. You need to update x264 sources to a newer version: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264/

Apple Silicon support in x264 was added at the end of 2020.